# Check result of PHP include

Tags: php, include

I've got my login and session validity functions all set up and running.
What I would like to do is include this file at the beginning of every page and based on the output of this file it would either present the desired information or, if the user is not logged in simply show the login form (which is an include).

How would I go about doing this? I wouldn't mind using an IF statement to test the output of the include but I've no idea how to go about getting this input.

Currently the login/session functions return true or false based on what happens.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is some of the code used in my login/session check but I would like my main file to basically know if the included file (the code below) has returned true of false.

```
    if ($req_method == "POST"){
        $uName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uName']);
        $pWD = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pWD']);
        if (login($uName, $pWD, $db) == true){
                 echo "true"; //Login Sucessful
                 return true;
            } else {
         echo "false";
         return false;
        }
    } else {
     if (session_check($db) == true){
         return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: `if != statement` `if = function`  ***I SPEAK TO EVERYONE, I'VE SAID THIS TOO MANY TIMES***

Comment: Sorry - you get what I mean, but very fair point!

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? Yes you can check if the file included, but do you actually mean have code in that included file that sets something which you can check?

Comment: `*if != statement if == function`

Comment: Basically - in my 'main' file, I want to see if the result of the included file is true or false.

Comment: "I want to see if the result of the included file is true or false", so there is a function in that file that returns true or false? **Please post your code!**

Comment: As I suspected. returning like that from a function is fine. You don't return in a file and get the result true or false by including it.

Comment: @ManofSnow `if` is a language construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mean

```
if (include 'session_check.php') { echo "yeah it included ok"; }
```

or

**logincheck.php'**

```
if (some condition) $session_check=true;
else $session_check=false;
```

**someotherpage.php**

```
include 'session_check.php';
if ($session_check) { echo "yes it's true"; }
```

OR you could be expecting logincheck.php to run and echo "true" in which case you're doing it wrong.

EDIT:

Yes it was the latter. You can't return something from an included file, it's procedure not a function. Do this instead and see above

```
if (session_check($db) == true){
     $session_check=true;
 } else {
    $session_check=false;
 }
```

Actually..

```
$session_check=session_check($db);
```

is enough

Depending on where you want to check this, you may need to declare `global $session_check;`  or you could set a constant instead.

Comment: I see! So then just simply use the $session_check var to determine what I want to do? Simple as that??

Comment: Yes, the file you're including sets that, and you can check it elsewhere.

Comment: I like the one under "actually". Thanks! I would like to avoid using globals due to their security though this isn't for exposure to the internet. It's for my companys intranent

Answer (score 0):

you could have an included file which sets a variable:

```
<?php

$allOk = true;
```

and check for it in you main file:

```
<?php

include "included.php";

if ($allOk) {
  echo "go on";
} else {
  echo "There's an issue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to display some confusion about how php includes work, so I'm going to explain them a little and I think that'll solve your problem.

When you include something in PHP, it is exactly like running the code on that page without an include, just like if you copied and pasted. So you can do this:

includeme.php

```
$hello = 'world';
```

main.php

```
include 'includeme.php';
print $hello;
```

and that will print 'world'.

Unlike other languages, there is also no restriction about where an include file is placed in PHP. So you can do this too:

```
if ($whatever = true) {
    include 'includeme.php';
}
```

Now both of these are considered 'bad code'. The first because you are using the global scope to pass information around and the second because you are running globally scoped stuff in an include on purpose.

For 'good' code, all included files should be classes and you should create a new instance of that class and do stuff, but that is a different discussion.

Comment: This will cause an error because your file names aren't encapsulated.